# Can I debug dotnet dll in Unity using Visual Studio with source project?

Tags: .net, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-debugging

I have access to dotnet project and dll that is built from it. The dll is placed in Unity Assets and the scripts inside it is used in components. Is there a way to debug these scripts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution. Need to put pdb file along with dll and then attach unity debugger.